# Teaching linear algebra. Is this equation a "linear equation"?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

Consider the equation $x+3=3(x+1)-2x$. Is this equation a linear equation?

I would say to my students that an equation in 1 variable is linear when it can be simplified to the form $ax=b$ where $a\neq0$. Also, I would mention that a linear equation in 1 variable has only 1 solution. Therefore, I would say that the equation $x+3=3(x+1)-2x$ is not linear because it can be reduced to $0x=0$ which has infinite solutions.

However, a colleague whose research area is algebra says that a linear equation is one that only involves polynomials of degree 1. Therefore, the equation $x+3=3(x+1)-2x$ is linear. Then, according to the definition of my colleague, the equation $x-x=0$ is linear as well.

I was thinking that maybe a third possibility is that according to the definition of "linear equation" only equations of the form "expression$=0$" can be classified as linear or non-linear.
In this case, the equation $x+3=3(x+1)-2x$ is not linear nor non-linear, but the equation $x-x=0$ would be linear.

What should be the definition for "linear equation" in 1 variable suitable for a math course?

Comment: Does it matter?  What do you need a precise definition of "linear equation" for, anyways?

Comment: As far as I am concerned, you are right and your colleague is wrong.  I do not consider $x + (-x) = 0$ to be a linear equation.  Unclear if others will agree.  Also unclear if there is only 1 answer, or whether the answer depends on a (non-universal) convention.

Comment: Such a definition is usually just a tool for classifying equations. The courses I’ve come across would state the most general formula for an equation (for example, $y’’+py’+qy=0$ Is the most general 2nd-Order linear ODE). So I guess the $ax=b$ idea is not bad. because it corresponds to standard definitions in linear algebra. Of course, never test the students on these definitions... only test them on problem solving ability

Comment: @EricWofsey if you have a linear equation (i.e. if the highest degree of the simplified polynomial is 1, and the coefficient of $x^1$ is $\neq 0$), then you are guaranteed that there is exactly 1 solution (i.e. root) of the equation, and you are guaranteed that the root is Real.  This assumes that all coefficients in the simplified polynomial are real numbers.

Comment: Would you rename the field to "Linear Algebra as well as the Algebra of Polynomial Equations Having Degree Zero"?

Comment: @Théophile good question.  Personally, no I would not.  If that means that I have to distinguish between Linear Algebra and the Algebra of Linear Equations, so be it.  In my opinion, the math theorems that involve the *degree* of an equation are too important to compromise.  Obviously, my opinion is very highly subjective, and I have never done any post-grad work in Math.

Comment: I would definitely call the equation $x+3=3(x+1)-2x$ linear. A "linear system of equations" is a system of equations of the form $Ax = b$, where $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix and $b$ is an $m \times 1$ column vector. There is no requirement for $A$ or $b$ to be nonzero. One might alternatively define a "linear equation" to be an equation of the form $L(x) = b$, where $L$ is a linear transformation. And there is no requirement for $L$ to be nonzero.

Answer (score 0):

> However, a colleague whose research area is algebra says that **a linear equation is one that only involves polynomials of degree 1**. Therefore, the equation $0=0$(*on simplification*)  is linear. Then, according to the definition of my colleague, the equation  is linear as well.

The problem is "The degree of a zero polynomial is not defined or $-\infty$". So saying that zero polynomial has degree $1$ is little vague as $0\equiv 0x\equiv 0x^2\equiv 0x^3\equiv.....$

> What should be the definition for "linear equation" in 1 variable suitable for a math course?

A linear polynomial $p(x)=ax+b, a\ne 0$ when equated to a real number $\alpha(say)$ i.e. $p(x)=\alpha$ is called a linear equation.